# File uploaded on a web application

Tags: spring-mvc, file-upload, upload

I'm developing a web app which allow the user to upload and view PDF files.

My question is where should I store the file uploaded by the user? They said that it takes a great toll storing it in the database. So if not in the database where should I store the files uploaded by the user? Can you give me a specific or sample path where I should store the files?

By the way I'm using `Spring MVC` if it would help to clarify my question.

And also this is what I've done with my controller so far:

```
@RequestMapping( value = "*/uploadPDF", method = RequestMethod.POST )
    public String uploadPDF( @RequestParam( defaultValue = "" )
    String message, @RequestParam( defaultValue = "" )
    String messageType, HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model, FileBean fileBean, BindingResult result )
    {
        model.addAttribute( "message", message );
        model.addAttribute( "messageType", messageType );
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String returnVal = Credentials.checkSession( session );

        if( returnVal != null )
        {
            return returnVal;
        }

        if( result.hasErrors() )
        {
            for( ObjectError error : result.getAllErrors() )
            {
                System.err.println( "Error: " + error.getCode() + " - " + error.getDefaultMessage() );
            }
            return "redirect:*/module?error";
        }
        return "admin/module";
    }
```

I haven't decided yet of how would I handle the file yet. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to storing a files, you have many options... It really depends on your use case.

- You can store the file in the database as a lob. Generally, it would be slower with more overhead, but you can access it from any application that has a database connection.
- You can store your file on your application server FileSystem. this is probably the best solution if you want it to be very effective.
- You can put your files in a content repository (Ex Apache Jackrabbit). It can be a good option if you want to share your file across multiple applications.
- ...

What are your requirements? Confidentiality, performance, files availability...

Comment: The option two can you give a more detail? Can I access the data between two machines? i.e ( first machine uploaded a new file, second machine should be able to view the new uploaded file ) And I want to know where is the application server FileSystem, sorry for a noob question.

Comment: What do you mean be a second machine? A machine that access the same application via HTTP or an application that is deployed on a other machine?

Comment: A machine that access the same application via HTTP, The application will just be available  via Intranet netowork

Comment: Just store the file path into the database with an id and use that id to retrieve the file on the FileSystem."where is the application server FileSystem" Its the file system of the machine that host your application.

Comment: Can you give an example? I already search the web but I really don't understand where specifically is that. Now the app is on it's development process where should I store it?

Comment: You can store the file on your local FileSystem during the development. Check that example : http://www.raistudies.com/spring/spring-mvc/file-upload-spring-mvc-annotation/

Comment: I forgot to ask, what if it is ready to deploy. Where should I store the files? Can you give a sample path?